# How to create a box with a superscript?

Tags: tables, formatting, boxes, superscripts

I want to create something the image below on Latex. So essentially it is a math function which is surrounded by a box with a superscript. And boxes can be within other boxes.

Any thoughts?

Thanks you very much!

[image: picture example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `scalerel`'s `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` feature allows `\mathbox` to be applied to super/subscripts as well (e.g., `...^{\mathbox{F}}`) and retain its proper scriptsize nature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\mathbox[1]{\mathord{\ThisStyle{%
  \fboxsep3\LMpt\relax\kern1\LMpt\fbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\kern1\LMpt}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbox{\neg s}^T \rightarrow \mathbox{
\Bigl(\mathbox{(\mathbox{r}^T\rightarrow \mathbox{\neg p}^F)
}^F \vee \mathbox{\neg t}^F\Bigr)}^F
\]

\[\mathbox{a}^{\mathbox{b}^{\mathbox{c}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\boxed` of `amsmath` with some help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\boxsym}[1]{%
  \mathord{\mspace{2mu}\boxed{\vphantom{by}#1}\mspace{1mu}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\boxsym{\lnot s}^T \rightarrow
\boxsym{
  \biggl(\boxsym{
    \bigl(\boxsym{r}^T\rightarrow \boxsym{\lnot p}^F\bigr)
  }^F \vee \boxsym{\lnot t}^F\biggr)
}^F
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]